# Correct way to execute periodic background tasks

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

So I need to execute periodic tasks in background, even if my app is closed. I did it by creating my service and restarting it in some period of time, using AlarmManager:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.i("MyService","On Command!");
         stopSelf();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }
```

As you can see, my service is intended to be started as not sticky, do his job and stop immediately.

Shedule (1 second for fast testing only, it actually causes wakelock):

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(

                alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000),
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyService.class), 0)
        );
    }
```

My service will start on boot or on alarm (each 1 second currently). However, I'm not sure if it's correct way to do what I want. I noticed, that most 3rd party apps use sticky services and they reside in memory all the time.

So my question is, when should I use sticky service?